# Unable to register new destination using RegisterDestination in Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

When I try to register any new subscription destination using RegisterDestination (Amazon MWS Subscriptions API) I received error:

"An exception was thrown while attempting to Create a Destination. This can happen if the Destination has already been registered."

I try many randoms (100% unique) urls.
ListRegisteredDestination return empty list.

Thank for help

My Request:

```html
POST /Subscriptions/2013-07-01?AWSAccessKeyId=myAccess-Key
  &Action=RegisterDestination
  &SellerId=My-Seller-ID
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &Timestamp=2017-01-27T18%3A48%3A28Z
  &Version=2013-07-01
  &Signature=cybKM%2BtLq4F%2Fv%2BZnGhPtyLHg%2FCiOk31WbG0tHmpGQFg%3D
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &MarketplaceId=MyMarketPlaceId
  &Destination.DeliveryChannel=SQS
  &Destination.AttributeList.member.1.Key=sqsQueueUrl
  &Destination.AttributeList.member.1.Value=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl.pl%2Famazon%2Fnotlistner HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.de
x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.